# rx.net locking up from use of ToEnumerable

Tags: c#, rx.net

I am trying to convert the below statement so that I can get the key alongside the selected list:

```
var feed = new Subject<TradeExecuted>();

feed
  .GroupByUntil(x => (x.Execution.Contract.Symbol, x.Execution.AccountId, x.Tenant, x.UserId), x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
  .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
  .Select(trades => Observable.FromAsync(() => Mediator.Publish(trades, cts.Token)))
  .Concat() // Ensure that the results are serialized.
  .Subscribe(cts.Token); // Check status of calls.
```

The above works, whereas the below does not - when I try and itterate over the list, it locks up.

```
feed
  .GroupByUntil(x => (x.Execution.Contract.Symbol, x.Execution.AccountId, x.Tenant, x.UserId), x => Observable.Timer(timespan))
  .Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(() =>
  {
      var list = x.ToEnumerable(); // <---- LOCK UP if we use list.First() etc
      var aggregate = AggregateTrades(x.Key.Symbol, x.Key.AccountId, x.Key.Tenant, list);
      return Mediator.Publish(aggregate, cts.Token);
  }))
  .Concat()
  .Subscribe(cts.Token); // Check status of calls.
```

I am clearly doing something wrong and probably horrific!

Going back to the original code, how can I get the Key alongside the enumerable list (and avoiding the hack below)?

---

As a sidenote, the below code works but it a nasty hack where I get the  keys from the first list item:

```
feed
  .GroupByUntil(x => (x.Execution.Contract.Symbol, x.Execution.AccountId, x.Tenant, x.UserId), x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
  .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
  .Select(trades => Observable.FromAsync(() =>
  {
      var firstTrade = trades.First();
      var aggregate = AggregateTrades(firstTrade.Execution.Contract.Symbol, firstTrade.Execution.AccountId, firstTrade.Tenant, trades);
      return Mediator.Publish(aggregate, cts.Token);
  }))
  .Concat() // Ensure that the results are serialized.
  .Subscribe(cts.Token); // Check status of calls.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All versions of your code suffer from trying to eagerly evaluate the grouped sub-observable. Since in v1 and v3 your group observable will run a maximum of 5 seconds, that isn't horrible/awful, but it's still not great. In v2, I don't know what `timespan` is, but assuming it's 5 seconds, you have the same problem: Trying to turn the grouped sub-observable into a list or an enumerable means waiting for the sub-observable to complete, blocking the thread (or the task).

You can fix this by using the `Buffer` operator to lazily evaluate the grouped sub-observable:

```
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
feed
  .GroupByUntil(x => (x.Execution.Contract.Symbol, x.Execution.AccountId, x.Tenant, x.UserId), x => Observable.Timer(timespan))
  .SelectMany(x => x
    .Buffer(timespan)
    .Select(list => Observable.FromAsync(() => 
    {
      var aggregate = AggregateTrades(x.Key.Symbol, x.Key.AccountId, x.Key.Tenant, list));
      return Mediator.Publish(aggregate, cts.Token);
    }))
  )
  .Concat()  // Ensure that the results are serialized.
  .Subscribe(cts.Token); // Check status of calls.
```

This essentially means that until `timespan` is up, the items in the group by gather in a list inside `Buffer`. Once `timespan` is up, they're released as a list, and the mediator publish happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i thought the `GroupByUntil` would not return until it batched up a number of objects within 5 seconds (per the last parameter)? At that points in the list would be grouped? Seems my understanding of the sequences may be very off.

Comment: `GroupByUntil` will terminate the grouped sub-observable after the terminating condition (5 seconds). If you use `GroupBy`, the grouped sub-observable lasts forever, though with buffer, they will emit every 5 seconds (assuming there's >= 1 item).

Comment: Ok will read up more - having an issue with the modified code you kindly advised on - seems it called the publish every 5 seconds (i nthe select method), the first call is fine, the second call happens and list is 0 elements. Is there a way to make it run so it doesnt call with a 0 element list?